# Teradata function IFACTIVITYCOUNT and LABEL in TOAD

Tags: teradata, toad

I need to run teradata queries in TOAD Point. The functions IFACTIVITYCOUNT and LABEL I used working in Teradata SQL assistant but not working in TOAD.  What is the correct syntax or if there is an alternative way to run these functions in TOAD?  The connection is connecting to teradata (data warehouse) on TOAD.

SELECT 1 FROM dbc.TablesV...

.IFACTIVITYCOUNT = 0 THEN GOTO OK

DROP TABLE...

.LABEL OK

Comment: Those are conditional execution scripting commands, which in TOAD Data Point would be accomplished by using Automation script functionality. (BTW - there should be a space or tab between .IF and ACTIVITYCOUNT)

Comment: Do you mean those dot functions can only be used in automation on TOAD and will not work in the toad editor window?  (thank you about the space for .IF! that was a typo)

Comment: The "dot functions" cannot be used in TOAD editor (because they are client commands and not SQL that would be processed by the database). Automation does provide for similar conditional execution functionality, but not using this syntax.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful.  Thank you!